# One large table or split into two smaller tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there any performance benefit to splitting a large table with roughly 100 columns into 2 separate tables? This would be in terms of inserting, deleting and selecting tasks? I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I'm sorry this is just a general question? As you can see several people have already answered!

Comment: While several people *have* answered, it would have been nice to see some example data / schema of your big table (which is what @Johan was getting at, I believe).  Just to make sure people can give you the most accurate / relevant answer to your **specific** issue.

Comment: Yes I see that and the answers are largely useless, as these things are highly dependent upon your situation. So the answers have to guess and assume and answer in a `if ... then`, `provided that.. then this might help`, `no`. All of which may or may not have any relation to your table. A 100 columns is way over the top BTW, you need to normalize.

Comment: +1 for the depending on usage comment.  The answer to this question is ENTIRELY based on the actual usage in the app.  For example, if this is for some user facing app, the users might only have access to see 25 columns, and the other 75 are used in the back-end processing.  In that case, it *could* be very beneficial to split the table among those lines.  It would be sacrificing batch processing time for a quicker response for the users.  Again, this is entirely dependent on the actual data and the trade-offs you're willing to make.

Comment: Is the table in [5NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_normal_form)? 5NF is always achievable and eliminates certain update anomalies, which usually yields benefits beyond those of performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of the fields is a CLOB or BLOB **and** you anticipate it holding a huge amount of data **and** you won't need that field very often **and** the result set will transmitted over a long pipe (like server to a web-based client), then I think putting that field in a separate table would be appropriate.

But just returning 100 regular fields probably won't tax your system so much as to justify a separate table and a join.

Answer (score 1):

The only benefit you might see is if a number of columns are only occasionally populated. In which case putting those into their own table and only adding a row when there is data might make sense in terms of overall row overhead and, depending on the number of rows, overall page count for the table(s). That said, this is one of the reasons they introduced [sparse columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) in SQL Server 2008.

For the maintenance and other overhead of managing two tables instead of one (especially given that people can act on individual tables if they choose), it's unlikely it would be worth it.

Can you describe what type of entity needs to have over 100 columns? Perhaps the data model is just wrong in the first place.

Comment: The data model is to do with call records, so theres lots of very small fields for various checks etc

Comment: And are a lot of these checks NULLable, or do all 100+ checks always have a value? Are they all `BIT` columns, or `TINYINT`, or larger?

Comment: Yes alot of them are nullable. Mainly bit, int, smallint, and a few nvarchar for good measure :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say no as it would take more execution time to join the 2 tables whenever you wanted to do something.

Answer (score 0):

I depends if you use these fields in the same time in your application.

These kind of performance improvements are really bad : you make your source code impossible to understand. If you have performance trouble with this table, add something (like a table containing the 15 fields you'll use in a request that'll updated via trigger), don't modify your clean solution.

If you don't have performance problem, don't do anything, you'll see later !