# database design - when to split tables?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Sometimes creating a separate table would produce much more work, should I split it anyway?

**for example:** In my project I have a table of customers, **each customer has his own special price for each product** (there are only 5 products & more products are not planned in the future), each customer also have unique days of the week when the company delivers to him the products.

Many operations like changing days/price for a customer, or displaying days & prices of all customers would be much easier when the days & product prices are columns in the customers table and not separate tables, so is it refuted to create only one big customers table in such case? What are the drawbacks?

**UPDATE:** They just informed me that after a year or so there's a chance that they add more products, they say their business won't exceed 20-30 products in any event.
I still can't understand why in such case when product's prices has no relation (each customer has his own special price) adding rows to Products table is better then adding Columns to Customers table?
The only benefit I could think of is that customer that has only 5 products won't have to 'carry' 20 nullable products (saves space on server)? I don't have much experience so maybe I'm missing the obvious?

Comment: "more products are not planned in the future". Never say never...

Comment: "Many operations [...] would be much easier when the days & product prices are columns in the customers table and not separate tables".  Really?  How hard is it to write a few `INNER JOIN` statements?  You want to add more columns when/if new products are added?

Comment: You need to distinguish between the normalized format of tables that is tremendously useful for keeping data up-to-date, and de-normalized versions of data that are important for reporting.  It sounds like you want a separate set of reporting tables, which might be updated daily rather than on-the-fly.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - I'm not saying it is **hard** but it's still more work, espically that the application has A LOT of operations, so why shouldn't I do it that way and save myself work? espically that new products are not planned and if they want to upgrade they'll pay me more then. And what about the days? 7 days a week is pretty constant?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Even if he needs separate reporting tables, the format would still likely be 'normalized' for that portion of the schema.  BornToCode - It's not more work, not if you **ever** have maintenance.  Studies show that something like 80% of development work is spent on maintenance, _not_ on initial production.  Properly normalize your initial database, and only generate a(n additional) denormalized schema if performance dictates.  Be professional to your client - don't take the 'easy' way out.  Also, a _completely_ denormalized structure can be difficult to work with easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearly, just saying that one should *always* normalize is not pragmatic. No advice is always true.

If you can say with certainty that 5 "items" will be enough for a long time I think it is perfectly fine to just store them as columns if it saves you work.

If your prediction fails and a 6th items needs to be stored you can add a new column. As long as the number of columns doesn't get out of hand with very high probability, this should not be a problem.

Just be careful with such tactics as **the ability of many programmers to predict the future turns out to be very limited.**

In the end only one thing counts: Delivering the requested solution at the lowest cost. Purity of code is not a goal.

Comment: Basically all the 'different' products are the same product, that just come in different sizes (it's eggs if you're curious..) so I do tend to trust the assumption that changes won't occur often. I would also like to hear your opinion about the 'days' as well, My instinct was to create a special days table, but then I found it more 'ungainly' to modify days for a customer etc. that way, so I started thinking maybe I should just add the days as columns in the Customers table?

Comment: Sure. I usually use the columns solution myself when the number of items is constant and small (like days of week or egg sizes). Easy and fast.

Comment: if I'll end up with something like 30-40 columns in a table, it won't have bad affect on performence? Is the only drawback in case the customer will modify the requirements one day? Why is everybody here rebuking me for this while in another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335654/one-large-table-or-split-into-two-smaller-tables) people supported such act?

Comment: Think of storing a row as 10 to 100 times more expensive than storing a column. for every column you add you save a row in your case. That is a great trade-off for perf in general if you are CPU bound which many OLTP servers are. People are rebuking you because programmers are trained to recognize patterns and anti-patterns. This is, in general but not in this special case, an anti-pattern. Don't worry too much about what other people think is right for you.

Comment: They just informed me that after a year or so there's a chance that they add more products, they say their business won't exceed 20-30 products in any event. I still tend to attach the products to the customers table since every customer has is own special price for each product and there are many operations (updating price, attaching editable gridview that shows all customer's prices etc. which will be simpler that way without constantly inner joining), when (and if) new products will add I'll add columns. Would you still advice storing products as columns with such circumstances? Thank you!

Comment: @BornToCode, I tend to say no. They'll add more products and they'll add product-variants (like color). I think you'd need to get really high benefit from the column-based strategy to justify it at this point. The requirements have become unstable and the amount of columns high.

Comment: I was afraid you're going to say that :) but I accept it. I really thank you because it's a crucial decision for me. If you could please do me a favor and explain me why in such case (product's prices has no relation, each customer has completely different price) adding rows is better than adding columns? (In products table I'll have in each row - customer id, product name, product price). The only benefit I could think of is that customer that has only 5 products won't have to 'carry' 20 nullable products (saves space on server)? I don't have much experience so maybe I'm missing the obvious?

Answer (score 2):

Normalization is all about data integrity (consistency), nothing else; not about hard, easy, fast, slow, efficient and other murky attributes. The current design almost certainly allows for data anomalies. If not right now, the moment you try to track price changes, invoices, orders, etc, it is a dead end.

Comment: And what if I have another special table - `Sales History` that saves all that info when the sale was performed? everything seems trackable? Could you please give an example to those data anomalies you're talking about (I could understand why normalization could be better for modifications  (e.g. IF new products will be added constantly), but in my specific example I couldn't understand what kind of data anomalies are expected?)

Comment: @BornToCode; easy -- see if you can update (change) any field (row-column intersection) for a specific customer/product .. so that you can get different data (which is supposed to be the same).

Comment: @BornToCode; anyway wikipedia covers it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms  including examples.

Comment: `(which is supposed to be the same)` - I'm sorry but I still didn't get it, in my case each customer has **his own** special price for each product? I tried to look in wikipedia, but unfortunately my chinese is not good enough to understand what are they talking about :)

Comment: Suppose there is a product which should have same price for all customers ($5). Can I update just for one customer to be $3 (break the rule)? I would say that each product has a **base-price** and each customer has **his own markup (discount)**; price belongs to product and markup to customer. Do read that wikipedia article,