# Linking databases for a management system using Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build a very basic management system website for a hypothetical insurance agency and i just cant wrap my head around how i should organize the database to make it so i can assign users to specific policies and have the ability to update/replace the user in case there are re-arrangements within the agency so policies can be reassigned to the proper agents. This would be used to display data based on login as well. There's 3 layers that i think i need. A User table for user data, a client data/policy table to store client and policy info, and then a table for tasks that would be assigned to policies. I need multiple users to have access to a policy and then the policy should have access to 1 row in the task table. Would it just be better to have a user table and large client table with the task columns inside rather than a separate table for the tasks? I've been banging my head with this for days so if anyone can help, i greatly appreciate it.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = ''
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(50))
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)

#Multiple assigned users can access
class Client(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    policy_number = db.Column(db.String(50), unique = True)
    expiration_date = db.Column(db.Datetime)

#Single "client" assigned to single row of tasks based on policy number
class PolicyTasks(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    step1 = db.Column(db.String(50))
    step1_completed = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    step2 = db.Column(db.String(50))
    step2_completed = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    step3 = db.Column(db.String(50))
    step3_completed = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    step4 = db.Column(db.String(50))
    step4_completed = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    step5 = db.Column(db.String(50))
    step5_completed = db.Column(db.Boolean)
```

I removed the code i used to attempt to create the relationships because it might honestly be more helpful to look at the base layout

Answer (score 0):

To wrap your head around how you should organize the database to make it so you can assign users to specific policies, take a look at the docs on the Flask website. I think the second example under One-to-Many is very similar to what you're looking to do http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/models/.

I would recommend keeping the tables separate and not jamming it all into one. Usually that leads to a slippy slope (in my experience) with tables with too many attributes to manage.

It can also mean slower query times because `Client.query.filter_by(username='peter').first()` would then always query the client data, policy data and whatever else you later on end up throwing in that table, when you may've only needed the policy data for that specific view/api route.

This other stackoverflow post might help too:
[database design - when to split tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511482/database-design-when-to-split-tables)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had intended on trying to do a one to many between the user and client( or many to one im not sure because i need multiple users to have access to 1 client), and then a one to one between client and tasks. the connection between client and tasks shouldnt need to be updated or edited but the one to many would need that capability. I just dont understand how i would write the code to do that. maybe i shouldnt separate the tasks stable from client and just put the data in 1 table.

Comment: The users have access to 1 client and _only_ 1 client? What I'm getting at is, is it one to many or many to many?

Comment: sorry, no the users will have access to multiple clients but i want the clients to only be accessed by its assigned users. Thats why i thought one to many or many to one would work but im not actually sure it does. the client would have access to only 1 task. Hopefully you can see why im struggling to get this. Sorry if im causing any confusion, its hard for me to explain something i dont fully understand

Comment: I think the reason it is difficult to wrap your head around is because you're trying to describe a many to many relationship as one to many or many to one. What you're looking for is the many-to-many sections of that post. Many to many doesn't really work in SQL with only the two tables.

Comment: What you'll end up with a table of all the users, a table of all the clients and table like the `tags` table in the example on the docs. When you want to see if a user with id=1 has access to client with id=2, then you see if there is an entry in a third lookup table where user_id=1 and client_id=2. If there is, that user has access. To give user with id=3 access to client_id=2 also, you'd just add another entry to the lookup table with user_id=3 and client_id=2. Hopefully that illustrates it ok.

Comment: ok i think im understanding now. I'll have 2 tables instead of 3, and use a many to many relationship. Thanks so much for your help, i really appreciate it!